# getting "Cannot GET /index.html" on express.js server in cpanel

Tags: node.js, express, hosting, cpanel

i wrote the following code in my app.js provided by https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

my application manager
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F0xx.png

i placed it in the /nodejsapp folder and also added .htaccess to the same as suggested by some tutorials.

i was expecting to get "Hello World!" but instead got "Cannot GET /index.html"
I am not providing any route to index.html so why is it saying so

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.